# Compare two files of different layout based on key value and extract output to third file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to compare two files based on key values and print the unmatched records from file 1. Delimiter used is Pipe `|`

- Output to be:

  ```
  I|234567|BCDE|234TFY|abc|12345
  ```
- File 1:

  ```
  I|123456|ABCD|123abc|xyz|23456
  I|234567|BCDE|234TFY|abc|12345
  ```

  Key cols: Col 2 and 5
- File 2:

  ```
  xyz|P|1001|123456
  bcd|P|1001|123467
  ```

  Key Cols: Cols 1 and 4

Can someone please suggest what is the correct way to do this through `awk`?

Comment: Do you only need the data from column 2 and 5 and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the following `awk` program:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{key1[FNR]=$1;key2[FNR]=$4;next}
           {if ($2!=key2[FNR] || $5!=key1[FNR]) print}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

- This will first parse `file2.txt` and build per-line lists of columns 1 and 4. We can see that we are parsing the first file on the argument list by asserting that `FNR`, the per-file line counter, is equal to `NR`, the global line counter (**But note** that this will break if `file2.txt` is ever empty!).
- Then, when parsing `file1.txt`, for every line the colums 2 and 5 will be compared to the lists filled while processing `file2.txt`, and if they don't match, print the line.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:

```
while read -r line;
do
myvar2=$(line | awk '{ print $2}')
if grep -Fxq "$myvar" file2
then
# code if found
else
# code if not found
fi
myvar5=$(line | awk '{ print $5}')
if grep -Fxq "$myvar5" file2
then
# code if found
else
# code if not found
fi
done < file1
```

Code is not tested. This should read out line by line from file1, column2 separate and column5 separate,  `awk '{ print $2 $5}'` should read 2 & 5 and check, if the myvar exists in file2